# Kernel / Linux location is memory, how to verify

Tags: linux, kernel, fpga

I'm running linux on a Atlas-SoC Kit/DE0-Nano-SoC Kit. 
Through u-boot I've placed the kernel at a different location.

```
mcboot=setenv bootargs console=ttyS0,115200 root=${mmcroot} rw rootwait;bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
mmcload=mmc rescan;${mmcloadcmd} mmc 0:${mmcloadpart} ${loadaddr} ${bootimage};${mmcloadcmd} mmc 0:${mmcloadpart} ${fdtaddr} ${fdtimage}
mmcloadcmd=fatload
mmcloadpart=1
mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk0p2 mem=744M memmap=744M$256M
```

the last line, request 744M starting at 256M offset.

No my question is, how can i verify that this actually happend? This since i'm reading mixed solutions online between using device-tree and memmap configurations. And i want to make sure, before i continue on writing the device driver section.

My /proc/iomem:

```
root@cyclone5:~# cat /proc/iomem 
00000000-2e7fffff : System RAM
  00008000-0077656f : Kernel code
  007d6000-00859433 : Kernel data
ff702000-ff703fff : /soc/ethernet@ff702000
ff704000-ff704fff : /soc/dwmmc0@ff704000
ffb40000-ffb4fffe : /soc/usb@ffb40000
ffc00000-ffc00fff : c_can_platform
ffc02000-ffc0201f : serial
ffc04000-ffc04fff : /soc/i2c@ffc04000
ffc05000-ffc05fff : /soc/i2c@ffc05000
ffd02000-ffd02fff : /soc/wd@ffd02000
ffe01000-ffe01fff : /soc/amba/pdma@ffe01000
fff01000-fff01fff : fff01000.spi
ffff0000-ffffffff : /soc/sram@ffff0000
```

any detailed explanations would be highly appreciated,

regards Auke

Answer (score 0):

Device tree and kernel parameter memmap both helps in reserving memory that will not be used by linux kernel. Take a look at [linux device tree memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt) documentation and [kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt).

You can use Emulator or high end debugger for example Trace32 to see memory contents.